# Setting syntaxHighlight property for Swagger UI with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore for a project. The version I started with was **5.5.1** and when rendering results with large bodies (20k json rows), the speed was very reasonable (the data fetch takes 50ms and the rendering took less than a second.  When I upgrade to **5.6.x**, the syntax is now highlighted (which looks nice) but slows the rendering of those results to over 20 seconds.  And once rendered, any action on the page that causes a refresh takes 20 seconds until the results are cleared.

After the usual searching, I want to try this solution (deactivating syntaxHighlight).  I'm not sure how to do this via Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.  Any suggestions?

```
SwaggerUI({
        syntaxHighlight: {
          activated: false,
          theme: "agate"
        },
        //url: path,
        ....
      });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem and after some digging in the source code i found that you can pass additional parameters to the ConfigObject this way (example showing how to disable syntax highlighting):

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("syntaxHighlight", false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!  I've upvoted but don't have the rep for it to show.