# Cant get code highlights in AspDotNet Core 3.1 Swashbuckle SwaggerUI

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm having `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.1.2` package with following setup in `Startup.cs` file:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSwagger(c => { c.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/swagger.json"; });

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/v1/swagger.json", "API");
        c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("syntaxHighlight", true);
    });
}


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
            new OpenApiInfo {Title = "My API", Version = "v1"});
    });
}
```

and my swagger UI looks like this:
[image]

but I expect the code to be highligted as on this picture:
[image]

As you see i have this line (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64696778/2470538)

```
    c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("syntaxHighlight", true);
```

With or without it, nothing changes.

Comment: For me,removing this code  `c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("syntaxHighlight", true);` works well.And if I change it to `false`,it will  become a situation like you.

Comment: `c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("syntaxHighlight", true);` with or without it, i still dont get the highlights. I've tried with new project with simplest config and still no context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
 {
    config.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems["syntaxHighlight"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["activated"] = true
    };
});
```

This code come from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832#issuecomment-942470952