# Filter for response body Swagger .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a Web Api returning a list of elements from a GET on Swagger. The problem is the fact that the UI freeze or slow down after the call because it seems that the list of elements retrieved from the GET is too big for the highlighting used which in returns cause the freeze. A solution that I have in mind is to truncate the **response body that we see on the Swagger**(the response should be complete outside of Swagger) such that it produces less work for the highlighting. Therefore, i saw that we can use filters for that such as IOperationFilters.. But i did not find a filter that could help me manipulate the Swagger body response after the call of the GET. Also, I can not remove the highlighting for the confort of the users of our Api. I don't know if it is possible I am still a newbie in all this stuff thank you for your time :).

- I tried to remove the Highlighting it works but I can't remove it for the users
- I tried to use Filters such as OperationFilter, DocumentFilter... but it does not seems to work with my situation or simply I did not find how to do it with those filters.

Comment: i Forgot to say that we work with .net core 3.1 :)

Comment: The response you see in swagger is simply the response you get from the actual api endpoint that does not know it has been called from swagger (and does not use any of the Swashbuckle middleware that is just for generating a swagger frontend). So if you start filtering the response it will be filtered for every user not just those coming from swagger. One thing you might think about maybe that the defaults for the problematic endpoint should be in a way that it does not retrieve that many data. Like a small paging value as default if the endpoint  supports paging of data.

Comment: @ralf okay too bad for the filtering then :/ thank you for your answer :) . I am not sure that i can do that paging of data but i will still try to look into that direction at least :). Do you know maybe if i can deactivate the highlighting only for that endpoint by any chance (I tried previously but it targets all endpoints)? Because another solution would be to do that for only this endpoint so that at least all the other endpoints will still have the highlighting and this endpoint will be faster due to highlight disabling. thank your for your time

Comment: Swagger seems to know about a highlightSizeThreshold that might help. So it will stop highlighting for bigger response at a parametrized size. For that you need to replace the standard Index.html used by Swashbuckle you presumably use and insert some javascript setting highlightSizeThreshold. Unluckily i didn't find any good sample or could one create one by myself without some mayor effort in doing so.

Comment: That's already plenty enough thank you very much :) i will look by myself

Comment: you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64696778/1752270) approach